# jQuery AJAX request called, does not return success/error. Session variable remains unset in next request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**Background:**

I have two webpages, login.html and library.html. When the desired username/password combination is entered on login.html, the username should be stored as a session variable via request to login.php using Javascript. The page is then redirected to library.html.
In library.html, there is another request to set a Javascript variable equal to the previously stored session variable, username.

**login.js section:**

```
function success(givenUsername)
{
//This part is definitely reached

    $.ajax({type:"POST",
        url:"login.php",
        data : {username: givenUsername},
        success : function(response) {
        alert(response);;        
        },
        error: function() {
        alert('ajax error');
        }
       });
    alert("checkpoint");
}
```

**which calls login.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

echo $_SESSION['username'];

?>
```

**After success() in login.js, redirects to library.html.
library.js section:**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_user.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();

while(xmlhttp.readyState != 4) {
}

this.user = xmlhttp.responseText;
alert(this.user);
```

**Which requests get_user.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['username'] === "admin" ? "librarian" : "undergraduate";

?>
```

If it matters, I am running this on a UwAmp local host server. The error log after logging in is:

[:error] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in \UwAmp\www\get_user.php on line 4

[:error] PHP Stack trace

[:error] PHP   1. {main}() UwAmp\www\get_user.php:0

**Problem:**

When get_user.php is requested, library.html just hangs. Also, neither the success nor error functions inside login.js every alert, and "checkpoint" is never reached. It is possible that this is a simple fix, but I am very new to PHP and AJAX and jQuery. It seems to me that it should work.

Comment: why are you using both `$.ajax()` and `new XMLHttpRequest();`?

Comment: Mostly because I am just messing around with different ways of doing things. Do you think that might affect something?

Comment: no, it wouldn't necessarily cause issues, but if you are going to use jQuery/ajax there is no reason to not use it throughout

Comment: You have `//This part is definitely reached`, but say that `alert("checkpoint");` is never reached? Have you checked your browser console log to see if there is any console messages/errors? I doubt it would cause an issue, but you do have 2 semi colons `;;` in `alert(response);; `

Comment: Yeah, I used to have another alert where I have the comment, so I know it gets there. It just does not seem to get past the ajax call. I just removed the semi-colon, but no change in behavior.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, there were multiple problems. First, I was trying to do the request inside a form but not as the action. Apparently, this does not work well. Also, I had not included the jQuery library (did not know that was a thing). Still experiencing some problems, but I am making progress.

Comment: What other issue(s) are you experiencing?

Comment: Now login.php works properly and the session variable is stored. For some reason, when the booksLibrary.html is loaded it just hangs. I get no errors in UwAmp's error log and none in my browser's console. It has to do with the while loop condition never being met. Not sure why it isn't though, just started looking at that.

Comment: After doing some testing, it seems that the readyState of my request is stuck at 1. I'm pretty unfamiliar with requests, so I'm not sure why that is.